# How to hide a form

Tags: c#

I want to hide my form when I press a button inside the form. When I do this,
something must be shown in the taskbar, and if I click that thing form will again come into visible state.

Edit: I am not supposed to minimize or resize the form.

Comment: taskbar ? do you maybe mean in the system tray?

Answer (score 6):

You have two options:

1. Use the standard minimizing behavior of the Windows Forms. In your button click handler, set the [`Form.WindowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx#) property to [`FormWindowState.Minimized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate.aspx) or just let the user use the standard minimize button. This will "hide" the form, but will leave its button on the taskbar, and the user can click it to bring the form back.

**EDIT:** Based on your question edit, you should use [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx#).

2. Close the form and add a notify icon in the task bar notification area (aka "system tray"). To do that, you need to add an instance of the [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx#) component to your form. Then, on your button click handler, you will call [`Form.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) to close the form. When the user wants to bring the form back, they will click on the syastem tray icon representing your app and you will open the form.

Here's an [VB.NET example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903898) of how to do this. It shouldn't be hard to translate in C#. You can also search for [`NotifyIcon`](http://search.live.com/results.aspx?q=notifyicon+.net&go=&form=QBLH) to see more examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
//this is Form object
//Option 1

this.Hide();

//Option 2

this.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does standard minimize button comply with the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

in the button code:

```
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Width = 0;
        Height = 0;
```

in say... the Activated form event:

```
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        Width = 800;
        Height = 500;
```

Would this effect be right for you?

Comment: The question is: keep the form in the task bar and hide the form, your answer is incorrect and the code i gave gives the effect (needs changes to not size the form on load etc)

So really... vote me down for giving a correct answer? are YOU kidding?

Comment: and yes i know the width and height change is in there.. but i took a punt on the border style being enough to ignore that requirement... hence my question "Would this effect be right for you?"

But thanks for the vote down, i love you

Comment: Technically, overlaying Notepad on top of the form would also achieve the desired effect. Would you consider it the right approach? :-)

Comment: he he, well considering the form won't be hidden when you move notepad... no :P. the requirement for not allowing to minimize the form is weird but thats exactly the effect asked for. so in the couple of mins i had to think that code at least works.

Comment: Also i wholeheartedly agree the system tray is much better solution (and more standard!) if thats an option...

Answer (score 1):

As nils said.

```
Hide();
// or 
Visible = false;

NotifyIcon trayIcon;
//....
trayIcon.Visible = true;
```

Show/hide the trayicon depending on forms visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Form's property "Opacity".

```
// Hide your windows frame
form1.Opacity = 0; 

/*
 * Your actions Here
 */

// Show your windows frame
form1.Opacity = 1.0;
```